# Local Level Model Not Fully Optimizing Irregular State

Tags: python, statsmodels

We used a local level model to fit this data:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural import UnobservedComponents


data = {
    'Basque': [3.85318463, 3.9456583, 4.03356173, 4.0234219, 4.01378197, 4.2859184, 4.5743361, 4.89895735, 5.19701498, 5.33890298, 5.46515301, 5.54591563, 5.61489573, 5.85218493, 6.08140542, 6.17009424, 6.2836334, 6.5555554, 6.81076856, 7.1051843, 7.37789168],
    'another': [3.54662963, 3.69044557, 3.826835, 3.87567838, 3.92173673, 4.2417882, 4.57533548, 4.83804641, 5.0813341, 5.15809788, 5.22365053, 5.33247651, 5.42944892, 5.67437885, 5.91552394, 6.06683787, 6.22764921, 6.53906013, 6.83797506, 6.98736082, 7.12489303]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

model = UnobservedComponents(data['Basque'], level='llevel', exog=data['another'])
fm = model.fit()
```

Which yields the following converged parameters:

```
sigma2.irregular    2.365834e-11
sigma2.level        4.032277e-03
beta.another        9.704585e-01
dtype: float64
```

But then we compared same results with `bsts` package from R and got basically same values for level and beta whereas irregular it was quite different: `0.16` for variance (0.38 for standard deviation).

We decided then to compute the loglikelihood of the residuals while ignoring the level component (as its variance is relatively low) to see what would be the most appropriate value for irregular, like so:

```
residuals = data['Basque'] - fm.params[-1] * data['another']
```

And then we computed loglikelihood for both standard deviations (5e-6 for statsmodels, 0.38 for R), like so:

```
stats.norm.logpdf(residuals, 0, scale=5e-6).sum() # statsmodels sd
-> -39342125822.669464

stats.norm.logpdf(residuals, 0, scale=0.38).sum() # bsts sd
-> -5.789754559185148
```

As it turns out, it's due this difference that we are observing conflicting results from both packages so I'd like to ask for help to understand why the `irregular` component is yielding values that doesn't seem to fully optimize loglikelihood for fitting the data.

For what it seems, statsmodels finds optimum values for the statespace by maximizing the [loglikehood](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/base/model.py#L874) of observed data; this being the case, shouldn't the final state converge to standard deviation of 0.38 as it further improves the objective cost?

As reference, [this issue](https://github.com/dafiti/causalimpact/issues/37) was opened on our library developed on top of statsmodels; it's a quite interesting problem related to causal impact inference and the irregular component is letting the Python package conclude with certainty that there's causal impact whereas R's concludes the contrary.

We tested with all stable versions of statsmodels but got same `irregular` sd results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question and comparison between the two packages. The difference is apparently coming from the different estimation methods: maximum likelihood in Statsmodels and Bayesian MCMC in bsts. It is not surprising that a difference would show up in a case like this, since the time series is so short.

The reason I say this is that, given `sigma.obs`, `sigma.level`, and `coefficients` from the bsts output, for any iteration of their MCMC algorithm, I can replicate their one.step.prediction_errors and log.likelihood for that iteration by applying the Kalman filter to the local level + exog model using the parameter values from that iteration.

They do have one difference from Statsmodels, which is that they set the prior for the unobserved state based on the first observation of the dataset and the variance of the dataset, which is probably not optimal (but shouldn't be causing any major problems). Statsmodels instead uses a diffuse prior, which again shouldn't cause any major discrepancies. As I mentioned above, when I use their prior, I can match their filtering output.

So the difference must be in the estimation method, and this could have to do with the details of their MCMC algorithm and the priors that they set. You could follow up with them to see if they have any intuition about how their setup might be affecting results.

**Discussion of residuals and loglikelihood computation**

> We decided then to compute the loglikelihood of the residuals while ignoring the level component (as its variance is relatively low) to see what would be the most appropriate value for irregular, like so:
>
> ```
> residuals = data['Basque'] - fm.params[-1] * data['another']
> ```
>
> And then we computed loglikelihood for both standard deviations (5e-6 for statsmodels, 0.38 for R), like so:
>
> ```
> stats.norm.logpdf(residuals, 0, scale=5e-6).sum() # statsmodels sd
> -> -39342125822.669464
>
> stats.norm.logpdf(residuals, 0, scale=0.38).sum() # bsts sd
> -> -5.789754559185148
> ```

The problem with this is that the estimate of the variance of the irregular component is not the same as the variance of the residuals in a model where the state is not a constant. Instead, the model is:

y_t = x_t \beta + \alpha_t + \varepsilon_t

and Var(y_t - x_t \beta | t-1) = Var(\alpha_t | t-1) + Var(\varepsilon_t | t-1)

Since Var(\alpha_t | t-1) = sigma2.level and Var(\varepsilon_t | t-1) = sigma2.irregular, the appropriate variance is sigma2.level + sigma2.irregular = 0.00403. If you do:

```
stats.norm.logpdf(residuals, 0, scale=0.00403).sum() # statsmodels sd
-> -205.4612464569425
```

Okay, so that's still smaller than the one from your original post computed by `bsts`, but this is because the state is not a constant, and so `residuals` does not contain the actual relevant residual for the loglikelihood computation. The actual loglikelihood computation is done using `fm.forecasts_error` with variances from `fm.forecasts_error_cov`.

Comment: Thanks @cfulton for this informative answer! Just wondering, how do you set the prior in statsmodels with the same strategy as bsts? I tried doing `model.fit(start_params=[0, 1, 1])` but it didn't change results. Also, is there some metric we could use, such as AIC, to further explain each model and compare results?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not straightforward at the moment to modify the prior for `UnobservedComponents`.

Comment: Because the estimation paradigms are different (classical estimation vs Bayesian estimation), there is not a consistent framework with which to evaluate the results from the different models.  In Statsmodels, we are maximizing the likelihood function whereas that is not what bsts is doing. For that reason, you will always find that our estimates will lead to higher log-likelihood values and smaller AIC values than the models generated by the parameters estimated by bsts.

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for your help! We'll update our library adding the information we learned in this answer :)!